# Sale of a rental house

Tags: real-estate

I have a rental house that I'm thinking about selling to the renters. They have lived there for 9 years. I am now 75 years old and no longer able to keep the house in shape when there is a problem.

What would be my best option? The house is paid for so there is not a problem with a mortgage.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  Your "best option" for what?  Are you asking whether to sell the house or not?

Answer (score 2):

Your best option would be to have the house appraised by at least 3 reputable real estate agents in your area, do some research yourself on how much similar homes in your area have sold for and are selling for, and work out a figure you would be happy to sell at.

If you want a quick sale and your tenants are willing to buy, offer them a slightly inflated price from the price you would be happy to sell at, say 5% above you price. This will allow some room in case the tenants want to negotiate.

If the tenants are not willing to pay your minimum price you should tell them that you will just place the property on the open market, and depending on who buys it the tenants might have to move out.

This will test if they are at all interested in buying the house or just messing you about, trying to get a bargin. If they don't come around, and you still want to sell it, then place it on the open market to get the best price you can.